# python - gc.collect() not work. How can I solve?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, del

I am new in python. And i am working big data. And i get MemoryError. I used gc.collect() but is not work. Please help and Thanks.

```
import gc

a=[[1,2],[3,4]]
b=[5,6]
a.append(b)
del a,b
x=gc.collect()
print(x)
```

Output == 0

Comment: If you read the doc for `gc.collect()`, it returns `The number of unreachable objects found is returned.`

Comment: So you're saying the code works?

Comment: But there is no reduction in RAM usage. I did not understand

Comment: Those objects are very small.  I don't know if you would see them in the RAM usage.  Also, running this code happens almost instantly, so I am not sure how you would observe it.

Comment: Thanks James. This is just an example. My original code contains much bigger data.